# MySQL Error #1064 in query using CASE and JOIN

Tags: mysql

Execution of the following statement returns an error:

```
SELECT co.id,co.user_id,co.cat_id,co.offer_name,co.cost,u.shop_name, CASE WHEN buy >= get THEN buy
        else get  END as buy FROM createdoffers co INNER JOIN categories ct ON ct.id=co.cat_id INNER JOIN users u ON u.id=co.user_id 
        WHERE ct.Head_id='$head' AND ct.id=co.cat_id ORDER BY co.buy DESC LIMIT 1
```

MySQL returns:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'get THEN buy
        else get  END as buy FROM createdoffers co INNER JOIN cate' at line 1
```

I cannot find the error, please explain what is wrong with this query.

Answer (score 0):

get is a keyword. escape it with

```
SELECT co.id,co.user_id,co.cat_id,co.offer_name,co.cost,u.shop_name, 
CASE WHEN buy >= `get` THEN buy else `get` END as buy 
FROM createdoffers co INNER JOIN categories ct ON ct.id=co.cat_id INNER JOIN users u ON u.id=co.user_id WHERE ct.Head_id='$head' AND ct.id=co.cat_id ORDER BY co.buy DESC LIMIT 1
```